# Magic COLORREF/RGB value to determine when to use light/dark text

Tags: c++, c, windows, rgb

Years ago, in my long lost copy of Charles Petzold's Windows 3.0 Programming book, there was a magic COLORREF or RGB value documented that you could use to check whether you should draw text in a light colour or a dark colour.  E.g. if the background colour was below this value, then use black text, if it was higher, use white text.  Does anyone know/remember what this magic value is?

Comment: How do you define "below" and "above" on two RGB values? Are you only using greyscale?

Comment: It seems like converting to HSL may be a better bet, and then you can check based on the L (or possibly S) component.

Comment: I am sure if you look at the RGB values themselves you would be able to calulate the tolerance. It sounds very interesting though!

Comment: I can't remember the mechanics of what you did with this value to determine if the colour was dark or light, but he definitely documented a way to do this.

Comment: It was actually a magic COLORREF value IIRC.

Comment: Which function was this magic value passed to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't tell about COLORREF but I've got good results using the [luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness) as threshold:

```
     Y= 0.3 * R + 0.59 * G + 0.11 * B
```

with colours expressed as a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0.

If Y>=0.5 I considered the background "light" (and used dark text), if Y<0.5 I did the opposite.

I remember I also used other formulas including the simple mean:

```
     L = (R+G+B)/3
```

but I didn't like the result. It seems logical to me that Green contributes to lightness more than Red and Red more than Blue.

Comment: Calculating the luminance works perfectly.  I will find that magic COLORREF value one day though... :)